# Экранирование кавычек для textarea

Tags: экранирование

На сайте есть форма вида

```
<form id="commentForm" name="form_edit" method="post" action="<?php echo general::link($tpl_folder.'/send') ; ?>">
<input type="text" name="FORM[title]" class="input_1" id="title_pls">
<textarea name="FORM[text]" id="text_pls" rows="30" class="text_1"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить сообщение">  
</form>
```

При наличии кавычек в title и textarea - данные с формы теряются.
Подскажите пожалуйста как экранировать эти поля?

Comment: Экранировать можно кавычки, но никак не поля. Попробуйте `name="FORM[\"title\"]"` или `name="FORM['title']"`

Comment: Если вопрос связан с экранированием содержимого полей при обработке, то при получении пост запроса, отфильтруйте php функцией `htmlspecialchars()`. Из вопроса не совсем понятно что вы имели ввиду.

Comment: Да, вопрос связан с экранированием содержимого полей при обработке.Подскажите пожалуйста где мне надо добавить функцию htmlspecialchars()? Я так понимаю это обработчик - action="<?php echo general::link($tpl_folder.'/send') ; ?>" А где его искать не знаю.

Comment: попробовал сделать так - не заработало <textarea name="FORM[text]" id="text_pls" rows="30" class="text_1"><? echo htmlspecialchars($FORM[text]) ?></textarea>

Comment: **так тоже не работает**   `<textarea name="FORM[text]" id="text_pls" rows="30" class="text_1"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['FORM[text]']);?></textarea>`